# Is there is a constraint to make sure one column has and only matched column

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem to set correct constraint to make sure one column has and only has one matched column within the table.

For example, company Apple has Bloomberg ticker `AAPL:US` and only has this ticker. Otherwise, SQL Server will notice there is a error.

I try to use constraint with unique, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your schema might be a standard one using a junction table.  That is, your tables might look something like:

```
company (id, name)
ticker (id, name)
company_ticker (id_company, id_ticker)
```

That is, the `company_ticker` table is a junction table which stores the relationships between companies and tickers.  Normally, this table would by default be many-to-many.  But if you want to restrict a company to having only one ticker, then you may place a unique constraint on the `id_company` column:

```
CREATE TABLE company_ticker (
    id_company INT NOT NULL,
    id_ticker INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company, id_ticker),
    CONSTRAINT cnstr UNIQUE (id_company)
);
```

With the above unique constraint in place, your schema will only allow a given company to have one relationship with some ticker.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! But, actually all the fields are in the same table, and there have other fields, such as value and YearMonth.

Comment: My answer doesn't change much.  Just move both name fields into the `company_ticker` table.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it